# What is markup objects in context of Android Span?

Tags: android, markup, spannable

What is markup objects in context of Android Span?

```
android.text.SpanWatcher
```

> When an object of this type is attached to a Spannable, its methods
>   will be called to notify it that other **markup objects** have been added,
>   changed, or removed.

What is the mean of markup objects here?

```
HTML
```

> HyperText Markup Language

**HyperText** Hypertext is text which contains links to other texts.

**Markup** ?

Please let me know what is Markup mean...

**EDIT**

> So the markup object is **Span**...thanks to pskink

Comment: question?  to ask or not to ask?

Comment: still what is your point?

Comment: what do we mean by term "markup"?

Comment: is it a theoretical question or you just want to know what is SpanWatcher for?

Comment: Yes its a theoretical question.... just like in HTML HyperText  = Hypertext is text which contains links to other texts. what you say about Markup = ...

Comment: so "markup objects" means: spans

Answer (score 1):

"To style text in Android, use spans! Change the color of a few characters, make them clickable, scale the size of the text or even draw custom bullet points with spans. Spans can change the TextPaint properties, draw on a Canvas, or even change text layout and affect elements like the line height. **Spans are markup objects that can be attached to and detached from text;** they can be applied to whole paragraphs or to parts of the text."

**"Spans allow you to implement multi-style text with finer grained customisation. For example, you can define paragraphs of your text to have a bullet point by applying a BulletSpan."**

Source: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568